# Not find DataSource in .rdl report

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

Created a report in SQL Server Report Builder. All good! Trying to bring it in `ReportViewer`, but writes an error

> For the data source 'DataSet1' has not been set an instance of the data source.

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\MyReport.rdl";
    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;      
    ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("code","100");
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

`reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources` is null. Why? In Report Builder all is good

XML `MyReport`

```
   <DataSources>
     <DataSource Name="NL">
       <ConnectionProperties>
         <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
         <ConnectString>Data Source=ACH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NL</ConnectString>
       </ConnectionProperties>
       <rd:SecurityType>DataBase</rd:SecurityType>
       <rd:DataSourceID>629e3b49-aebf-48dc-bb89-f47956feaef8</rd:DataSourceID>
     </DataSource>
   </DataSources>
   <DataSets>
     <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
       <Query>
         <DataSourceName>NL</DataSourceName>
         <QueryParameters>
           <QueryParameter Name="@code">
             <Value>=Parameters!code.Value</Value>
           </QueryParameter>
         </QueryParameters>
         <CommandText>SELECT
   window.code
   ,window.window
   ,window.[user]
 FROM
   window
 WHERE
   window.code &lt; @code</CommandText>
```

Comment: The `.rdl` is the **server-side** format for your report - if you want to run this locally, using `LocalReport`, you need a `.rdlc` file and you need to define the database connections locally, too - those on the server won't do you any good...

Comment: So we have to work with the component reportViewer1.ServerReport? Generate .rdl locally is impossible, you need to programmatically set the DataSource?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not use the `ServerReport` option on the client. You should download your report data from the server, in two steps:

- Generate report file **on the server** and save it locally in `rdlc` format
- Generate report datasource as `DataSet`, and set datasource programmatically, something like this:

  ```
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(GetReportParameters(parameter));

  foreach (var source in ResultDataSet.Tables)
  {
      reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(source.Name, source);
  }
  ```